# get the entire row using distinct on one column in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, distinct

I need to retrieve the entire rows collection using `distinct` on one column in `LINQ`.

i am getting the `Distinct` using `GroupBy` but it only selects the one column values instead i need entire row.

**this list returns the collection which is unique in ThumbnailAltText column BUT only returns that column rather than entire row values. so i had to use `var` instead of `type`

```
 var catlist = _db.ac_Categories
    .Where(c => c.VisibilityId == 0 && c.ThumbnailAltText != null
        && (!c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("gifts/")
        && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("email/")
        && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("news/")
        && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("promotions/")
        && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("the-knowledge/"))).ToList()
        .GroupBy(c=> c.ThumbnailAltText.Trim().Distinct()).ToList();
                                .GroupBy(c=> c.ThumbnailAltText.Trim().Distinct()).ToList();
```

**same thing does not work with `type` like this and i am getting error.**

```
List<ac_Categories> catlist = _db.ac_Categories
        .Where(c => c.VisibilityId == 0 && c.ThumbnailAltText != null
            && (!c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("gifts/")
            && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("email/")
            && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("news/")
            && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("promotions/")
            && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("the-knowledge/"))).ToList()
            .GroupBy(c=> c.ThumbnailAltText.Trim().Distinct()).ToList();
                                    .GroupBy(c=> c.ThumbnailAltText.Trim().Distinct()).ToList();
```

ERROR: `The 'Distinct' operation cannot be applied to the collection ResultType of the specified argument.`

**EDIT: I need a collection and not the first record, ID and other columns contains diff values only ThumbnailAltText my contain duplicates**

Comment: Could you provide ac_Categories type definition

Comment: its a entity created using database first approach... its a very large table so cant provide that in here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Distinct` on a string returns unique characters. I assume you want to return all rows, but every row should be unique according to the `ThumbnailAltText`, is that correct?

Then this should work, it returns simply the first row of each group:

```
var catlist = _db.ac_Categories
    .Where(c => c.VisibilityId == 0 && c.ThumbnailAltText != null
        && (!c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("gifts/")
        && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("email/")
        && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("news/")
        && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("promotions/")
        && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("the-knowledge/")))
     .GroupBy(c=> c.ThumbnailAltText.Trim())
     .ToList()
     .Select(g => g.First())
     .ToList();
```

Comment: is this going to return entire row or just one column values?

Comment: @patel.milanb: it returns the entire row.

Comment: let me try it and will let you know ... so if it returns the entire row i can use the return type as List<ac_Categories> right? instead of var

Comment: this gives me error: The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead.

Comment: @patel.milanb: Then try to prepend the `ToList` before the `Select` as you've already done in your code (edited my answer).

Answer (score 1):

also you may use [Distinct(IEnumerable, IEqualityComparer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/Library/bb338049%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) extension like this

```
public class CategotiesEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<ac_Categories>
{
    public bool Equals(ac_Categories x, ac_Categories y)
    {
        return x.ThumbnailAltText.Trim() == y.ThumbnailAltText.Trim();
    }

    public int GetHashCode(ac_Categories obj)
    {
        return obj.ThumbnailAltText.Trim().GetHashCode();
    }
}

List<ac_Categories> catlist = _db.ac_Categories
    .Where(c => c.VisibilityId == 0 && c.ThumbnailAltText != null
        && (!c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("gifts/")
        && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("email/")
        && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("news/")
        && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("promotions/")
        && !c.ThumbnailAltText.StartsWith("the-knowledge/")))
    .Distinct(new CategotiesEqualityComparer())
    .ToList()
```

Comment: Error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[WebMgr.ac_Categories] Distinct[ac_Categories](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[WebMgr.ac_Categories], System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1[WebMgr.ac_Categories])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Extension for IEnumerable, not IQueryable

Comment: yup... i got it... i have to use AsEnumerable()